# os.rename works from editor terminal but fails when launched from windows explorer

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
import shutil
import os
import datetime


SETUP_FILE = r'G:\Documents\Python\backup_tools\user.txt'


def setup():
    print("dubug 04")
    print('Enter your Chrome bookmark directory.')
    print(r'Standard one is: C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default')
    bookmarkfolder = input('> ')

    print('Enter the folder you want to save the backup files in.')
    print(r'For example: C:\Users\<USER>\Desktop\Chrome Bookmarks')
    backupfolder = input('> ')

    with open(SETUP_FILE, 'w') as txt:
        txt.write(bookmarkfolder + '\n' + backupfolder + '\n')

    copy()


def copy():
    print("debug 01")
    with open(SETUP_FILE, 'r') as txt:
        user_list = [line.strip() for line in txt]

    shutil.copy(user_list[0] + r'\Bookmarks', user_list[1])

    new_name = datetime.date.today().strftime('Bookmarks%Y%m%d')
    try:
        print("dubug 02")
        os.rename(r'G:\Documents\99. Backup\Bookmarks', new_name)
    except WindowsError:
        print("debug 03")
        os.remove(new_name)
        os.rename(r'G:\Documents\99. Backup\Bookmarks', new_name)


def checksetup():
    try:
        with open(SETUP_FILE, 'r') as txt:
            txt.seek(0)
            line = txt.readline()
        if 'C:' in line:
            copy()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('file not found')
        setup()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    checksetup()
```

Here's the output from console in editor, which works and creates the backupfile with the correct name if it doesn't exist and replaces it if it already exists:

```
runfile('G:/Documents/Python/backup_tools/chrome_bookmark_backup2.py', wdir='G:/Documents/Python/backup_tools')
debug 01
dubug 02
debug 03
```

But here's the output when I run from windows explorer, that doesn't create the bookmarks file and seems to end up running checksetup() again, this time going to setup() as the exception appears where this same try/except already brought it to copy() which you can see from debug 01 and debug 02 in the output:
[image]

Can anyone give me direction on why this is failing when run from windows explorer using python or from windows terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The error in the code is in the creation of new_name in the middle of the copy() function. It is missing the directory. Here is the corrected line of code:

```
new_name = os.path.join(user_list[1], datetime.date.today().strftime('Bookmarks%Y%m%d'))
```

2. What was happening was when I ran in spyder or sublime text, the rename function assumed I wanted the file in the same directory as my script when I didn't provide the directory within new_name. When run from the terminal os.rename does not accept you have not provided a directory, rather raises the exception: FileNotFoundError.

The issue for me is solved but if anyone has more information on why the errors are handled differently between IDE and external terminal it would be a more valuable answer to the original question.